# How do I construct my WHERE clause to pull records based on this specific criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, where-clause

I am using `SQL Server 2014` and I have a `T-SQL` query running against a specific Table (t1).
Table `t1` includes 3 columns named [HR_LeftDate], [Payroll_LeftDate] and [Status].

In that table, there are records which have their [HR_LeftDate] and [Payroll_LeftDate] as 'NULL' and some other records which have a BLANK (for both columns).

I need to extract those records and my T-SQL query stands as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM [t1]
WHERE ([HR_leftDate] IS NULL AND  [Payroll_leftDate] IS NULL )
   OR ([HR_leftDate] = '' AND  [Payroll_leftDate] = '') AND [Status] = 'Left'
```

Something must be wrong in my WHERE clause where I am filtering the [HR_LeftDate] and [HR_PayrollDate] as I am not getting those specific records.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) And remember that AND goes before OR.

Comment: Are you storing your dates as text?

Comment: I'm *sure* it's just a quirky way of the OP checking it's `1900-01-01` @TimBiegeleisen 

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I can't say since I only have access to a VIEW to extract my data.

Comment: Do not store dates as strings.  It is that simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply ISNULL clause to make the nullable values as empty strings and do comparison like given below:

```sql
SELECT * FROM [t1]
WHERE ISNULL([HR_leftDate],'') = ''  AND ISNULL([Payroll_leftDate],'') = ''
AND [Status] = 'Left'
```

Comment: I suspect that this is the "answer," though the OP should not store dates as text in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The `AND` operator has a higher [precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) than the `OR` operator, so you probably need to change the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [t1]
WHERE 
   (
      ([HR_leftDate] IS NULL AND [Payroll_leftDate] IS NULL) OR
      ([HR_leftDate] = '' AND  [Payroll_leftDate] = '') 
   ) AND 
   ([Status] = 'Left')
```

Your current `WHERE` clause applies the following conditions:

```
WHERE 
   ([HR_leftDate] IS NULL AND  [Payroll_leftDate] IS NULL) OR 
   ([HR_leftDate] = '' AND  [Payroll_leftDate] = '' AND [Status] = 'Left')
```

As an important note (as is mentioned in the comments), always store date and time values uisng the appropriate `date` and `time` data types.